# Download Document from SharePoint Online using c# webclient stopped working

Tags: sharepoint-online, webdav

Download Document from SharePoint Online using c# webclient stopped working!

I have been using this code to download documents from SharePoint Online for years. Since 8th of May I'm getting 401 Error.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");

SecureString securePassWord = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray()) securePassWord (c);
WebClient.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassWord);

byte[] fileBinary = webClient.DownloadData(fileUrl);
```

Should it still be working?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Hello @M.Rob, I'm afraid you're going to need to include a lot more information than this. Has the version of sharepoint changed, if so what was it and what is it now? Has some new authentication been added to the sharepoint instance? Have the credentials you've been using been changed recently? All of those answers and any other information you have is vital to getting an answer which will fix your problem.

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn thanks for the reply! No Changes at all. Please note, we are using SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Comment: SharePoint Online is hosted, managed, and updated by Microsoft. My guess is they have made a change to the authentication of the endpoint you're trying to reach. As such, your code is now out of date. What is the value of fileUrl, you could then look for patch notes about any authentication changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's for :

```
securePassWord.AppendChar(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I detailed an answer here. Please check.
Trick is to get the cookie and pass as header.
https://saratchandra.net/2015/08/18/is-it-that-difficult-to-read-a-file-from-sharepoint-site/